# How to encrypt file using sops using a key stored in Azure Vault in China

Tags: azure, encryption, mozilla-sops, azure-china

I'm trying to implement the sops tool in order to manage secrets in my terraform code.
I already installed sops sucessfully, and executed the following commands:

```
az cloud set --name AzureChinaCloud
az login 
az account set ###-###-###-#### (subscription id)
```

I also created an enviornment variable: AZURE_ENVIRONMENT="azurechinacloud"
When I execute the command to encrypt a file using sops:

```
sops --encrypt --azure-kv https://[KEY_VAULT].vault.azure.cn/keys/[KEY]/[KEY_ID] secrets.yaml > secrets.enc.yaml
```

This command returns the following:

> [AZKV]   time="2024-01-09T17:01:01Z" level=error msg="Failed to create
> Azure authorizer" error="Invoking Azure CLI failed with the following
> error: ERROR: AADSTS500011: The resource principal named
> https://vault.azure.net was  not found in the tenant named ****. This
> can happen if the application has not been installed by the
> administrator of the t enant or consented to by any user in the
> tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong
> tenant. Trace ID: ***** Correlation ID: **** Timesta mp: 2024-01-09
> 17:01:00Z\r\nInteractive authentication is needed. Please run:\r\naz
> login --scope [https://vault.azure.net/.default\r\n"](https://vault.azure.net/.default%5Cr%5Cn%22) Could not generate
> data key: [failed to encrypt new data key with master key
> "https://[KEY_VAULT].vault.azure.cn/keys/[KEY]/[KEY_ID]": Invoking
> Azure CLI failed with the following error: ERROR: AADSTS500011: The
> resource principal named https://vault.azure.net was not found in the
> tenant named *****. This can happen if the ap plication has not been
> installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any
> user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to
> the wrong tenant. Trace ID: *** 4 Correlation ID: ***** Timestamp:
> 2024-01-09 17:01:00Z Interactive authentication is needed. Please run:
> az login --scope https://vault.azure.net/.default ]

My user has the needed permissions in order to use the keys in my key vault.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

---